# White, red and green screen flicker

Tags: 12.04, ati, graphics, flicker

I updated 12.04 this morning through the update manager (can't remember what it was, but it was only one thing) and everything was fine up until a few minutes ago when my screen changed and began flickering a partitioned white, red and green.  I can't access any of the terminals so I'm not sure what to do.

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers.

Edit:  I'm running a Dell Studio 1558 which has an ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5470

Comment: Please provide more info like video card, etc.

Comment: Updated info on the main thread.

Comment: Do you get the same result if you attach the system to a different screen? This sounds like hardware failing to me.

Answer (score 0):

Create the file (as root) `/etc/modprobe.d/radeon-kms.conf`, and add the following line:

```
options radeon modeset=0
```

Reboot, and see what happens. It should fix your problem.